# Drupal как реализовано! Интересный пример

Tags: css, drupal

https://www.drupal.com/ 
Подскажите, уважаемые знатоки, как реализована вёрстка и особенно разворот блока при наведении? Хотелось бы получить ответ имеющий точное основание - верную вёрстку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разворот блока при наведении. Реализация на чистом CSS, без JS. Честно украдено [отсюда](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip).

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}

/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background-color: #fee;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
   FRONT
  </div>
  <div class="back">
   BACK
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Что касается вёрстки, то там много элементов. Если ограничиваться блоком с "флипперами", то, например, так:

```css
.outblock {
    text-align: center;
}
.inblock {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0.25em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outblock">
    <div class="inblock" style="background-color: #fee;">
        <h1>BLOCK 1-1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inblock"  style="background-color: #efe;">
        <h1>BLOCK 1-2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inblock"  style="background-color: #eef;">
        <h1>BLOCK 1-3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inblock"  style="background-color: #ffe;">
        <h1>BLOCK 2-1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inblock"  style="background-color: #fef;">
        <h1>BLOCK 2-2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inblock"  style="background-color: #eff;">
        <h1>BLOCK 2-3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Это не крал...

Comment: как это вам удалось ? как нашли решение ?

Comment: @LenovoID Google. Поисковая строка "css double-sided block". Первая ссылка ("CSS Flip Animation").

Comment: я слов то таких не знаю - спасибо - ответ лучший как видите

Comment: @LenovoID Спасибо. Рад был помочь.